# I am planning to make Instant messenger on android and need some guidance

Tags: php, android, mysql, networking, network-programming

I have connected my android app with php and mysql.
I have used HttpClient in android to connect with php 
The problem is i get a response from server only if i send a request.
So if I am 'X' and I want to send some message to 'Y'
then how will 'Y' receive it.
Should the client continously poll server every 'n' seconds for new messages? I feel this will be inefficient.
Any other alternative ??
Is using HttpClient the best way or should I use some other method ?

Comment: maybe you should have a look at socket connecitons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [cloud to device messaging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google cloud messenger. And for more info there is a research paper on this topic. It might be useful for you .

http://www.academia.edu/4839374/Study_on_client_server_interaction_in_an_android_Smartphone_messaging_application_through_prototype_implementation